# Replacing German Characters (Characters with Umlauts)

Tags: sql-server

When I do a simple select like case 1 below, the replace function works as expected.

**CASE 1**

```
select replace ('äaü','ä','ae')
```

**RESULT**

```
aeaü
```

When I do the same on the column in a table it replaces even 'a' with 'ae' which in unexpected.

**CASE 2**

```
select replace (column_1,'ä','ae') as actual_text
from table
```

**RESULT**

```
aeaeü
```

How can I achieve the expected results in case 2?

Comment: It depends on the *collation* you use.

Comment: `select replace (column_1,N'ä','ae') as actual_text
from table`

Comment: What if you use proper `N` prefixes on your string literals?

Comment: even when I use N prefix, I had the same issue...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks @juergen d!

My database default collation was set to **Latin1_General_CI_AI** earlier.

Now i executed the following statement which gives me expected results

```
select replace (column_1 collate Latin1_General_CI_AS,'ä','ae') as actual_text
from table
```

i.e, the collation property has been changed from Accent insensitive to Accent sensitive.

Comment: _AS _AI stand for Accent sensitive/insensitive not for Ascii insensitive that means nothing.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT 'Citroën' COLLATE Ukrainian_CI_AI -> return Citroen